# Can a can of beer keep its taste after emptied into a bottle and stored for a week?

Tags: storage, alcohol

I don't have much experience with alcoholic drinks, and how it's treated after purchase.
but I know that a can of non-cold (room temp) beer can be stored for as long time before cooling in a refrigerator.

But if I purchased a non-cold can of beer and emptied it in another bottle (plastic), would it keep its original taste and can still have the property of being stored for a long time before putting it in the refrigerator?

*sorry for my English

Comment: I expect it would rapidly go flat, but I’ve never tested this myself.

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately, no. The can shouldn't be opened before direct use

Comment: It will loose its property and taste after a while.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, beer will go flat if you put it in a plastic bottle after a few hours. However, the best option is a beer saver, which is a cap made out of silicone. This can be put onto any type of bottle, and the beer's carbonation stays intact